# bibtex-reformat and bibtex-sort hangs emacs

Tags: bibtex

I am running emacs 25.3 and have been having issues with my bib files.  Whenever I edit the bib file and reformat/sort the entries it takes a long time to carry out the reformatting (15-20 seconds) and after it is finished emacs hangs.  I noticed CPU usage on one core goes to 100% while reformatting and stays there after completion.  I need to kill emacs to get out of this loop.

The bib file I have is not terribly large, several hundred entries with a total of ~8k lines.  I ran a test on a smaller bib file (~2k lines) and experienced the same issue.  Are my bib files too large?  Is there a way to identify which part of the reformat/sort is causing it to hang?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *hangs* Emacs. What behavior do you see? Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If so, consider `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew You commented as I wrote my answer below.  By hang, I mean I cannot do anything in emacs (cannot move cursor, cannot change buffers, cannot close buffer, etc.).  The ONLY thing that still works is C-g followed by hitting the top-left "x" to close the window.  However, as you suggested, the issue was in the init file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the idea this may be a problem in my init (.emacs) file so I began commenting out sections and zeroed in on wc-mode and linum-mode.  I have read that combining word-count mode and linum-mode is problematic for scrolling large files (I've never experienced this), but this is the first I have heard of it interfering with bibtex-mode.  Here are three solutions (all require completely disabling word count mode...might as well uninstall it):

1. comment out both modes.  This solved the problem and the .bib files takes roughly 1 second to save.
2. permanently disable wc-mode.   Disable linum-mode when in bibtex-mode using the following hook:

   `(add-hook 'bibtex-mode-hook (lambda() (nlinum-mode 0)))`

The .bib file takes roughly 10 seconds to save

3. permanently disable wc-mode, install nlinum and enable it in the .emacs file.  This works without problem and the .bib file takes roughly 5-10 seconds to save.

The optimal solution as far as performance is concerned is completely disabling word counts and line numbering.  I prefer line numbering when writing (code, latex, etc.), so option 3 provides a good trade off.  I'll keep this posted for posterity in case anyone else has similar problems.